# How to change /blog url to some other url in Magento?

Tags: wordpress, magento, blogs

I am a beginner and my site is www.ideabaz.com. I want to redirect request at www.ideabaz.com/blog url to www.ideabaz.com/wp

Comment: Hi!
Have you tried anything?
Any problems you've ran into in particular?
There is a host of different starting points to introduce redirects.
You could do this in your webserver, via htaccess rules, or maybe via magento code even.

Comment: Yep , I tried to overwrite url redirection but unable to find any option in magento for that. Then i changed the directory name from wp to blog but after doing that css was not loading properly